# Which shots are we reviewing at least twice daily in shul?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

At least twice every day, each shul has someone who says *chazarat hashat"z* - he is reviewing the shots.

Which shots need to be reviewed? G-d forbid - did someone shoot people in the shul? Is a doctor giving shots that weren't properly administered?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I always thought it was like 'returning fire'-- returning the shots.

Answer (score 8):

The Nefesh HaChaim writes ([2:13](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A9_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%91/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%99%D7%92)):

> שבכל פעם שמתפללין יוגרם תקונים חדשים בסדור העולמות
>
> Every time we daven, it establishes new orbits for the planets

When we daven, we are firing spiritual missiles into space, which change the orbital patterns of the celestial bodies and knock them into an altered orbit.

Afterwards, we review these "shots" to make sure we haven't set any planets on a collision course with Earth.

Therefore, the Shulchan Aruch writes ([Orach Chaim 53:5](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x418)) that the wisest man is a good choice for the reviewer of the shots, because he will have the greatest grasp of astronomy.

Answer (score 5):

No, no, no!

It's referring to the process of making a lechayim after shul! One is obligated to give a yasher koyach to the chazzan upon his completion of tefillah. This is accompanied by a demonstration of said koyach by taking a shot with him. Since he has to display that his koyach is sufficient to lead the whole of the tzibbur, he must take an ***additional*** shot to show he is capable of taking on the burden of the congregation on top of his own obligations.

That is why the Chazzan must perform chazarat hashots.